# rxjs, how do I groupBy into an object?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

So I've seen a lot online, one of the big problems I'm encountering is half the examples either don't compile in typescript, or they use now deprecated methods in RxJs 6.

this is what I'm starting with

```
@registrah([
  { token: 'test', useValue: 1},
  { token: LoggerDefault, useFactory: memoize( createDefaultLogger ) },
  { token: LoggerTypeOrm, useFactory: memoize( createTypeOrmLogger ) },
  { token: LoggerSecurity, useFactory: memoize( createSecurityLogger ) },
])
```

my current attempt is this

```
  const res = from(registrations).pipe(groupBy(
    (p) => {
      const {token, ...provider } = p;
      return Object.keys(provider)[0];
    }),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(
      reduce((acc: Array<AllProvider<any>>, cur) =>[...acc, cur], [])
    ))
  );
  res.subscribe((next) => console.log(next) );
```

which is outputting

```
[ { token: 'test', useValue: 1 } ]
```

```
[
  { token: 'defaultLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
  { token: 'typeormLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
  { token: 'securityLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] }
]
```

what I want is

```
{ useValue: [ { token: 'test', useValue: 1 } ] },
```

```
{
 useFactory: [
  { token: 'defaultLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
  { token: 'typeormLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
  { token: 'securityLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] }
]}
```

and since I've been fighting with it for far too long I'd also like to see the answer for

```
{ 
  useValue: [ { token: 'test', useValue: 1 } ],
  useFactory: [
    { token: 'defaultLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
    { token: 'typeormLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] },
    { token: 'securityLogger', useFactory: [Function: bound variadic] }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below.

The examples assume you've got all the items you're working with upfront (i.e. completed). If you don't (i.e. responses incoming from AJAX), they won't work.

Note that to get to your second desired form, there is no need to use `groupBy` whatsoever.

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { reduce, groupBy, map, mergeMap, toArray } = rxjs.operators;

const registrations = [
  { token: 'test', useValue: 1 },
  { token: 'defaultLogger', useFactory: new Function() },
  { token: 'typeormLogger', useFactory: new Function() },
  { token: 'securityLogger', useFactory: new Function() },
];

// [{ useValue: ... }] | [{ useFactory: ... }, { useFactory: ... }, ...]
from(registrations).pipe(
  map(r => {
    const { token, ...provider } = r;
    const groupKey = Object.keys(provider)[0];
    return { groupKey, value: r };
  }),
  groupBy(r => r.groupKey, r => r.value),
  mergeMap(g => g.pipe(
    reduce((a, r) => {
      if (!a[g.key]) a[g.key] = [];
      a[g.key].push(r);
      return a;
    }, {}),
  )),
).subscribe(console.log);

// { useValue: [ ... ], useFactory: [ ... ] }
from(registrations).pipe(
  reduce((a, r) => {
    const { token, ...provider } = r;
    const key = Object.keys(provider)[0];
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
    a[key].push(r);
    return a;
  }, {})
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.4/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: in the 2nd example I get

`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'`

Comment: for the 1st one, looks like I'm still getting the results I did...

Comment: RE: first example, apologies for the confusion there. Indeed I messed up and forgot the grouped observables must be mapped into the form where each emission is an object with a key against an array value. As for your TS error, you'll need to annotate the `a` used inside all the the `reduce` operators. A quick workaround would simply be `a: any`, otherwise you'll need to reverse-engineer the correct type, which is harder to help you with since I can't see all the TS types that pertain to your snippets.